# Arrange strings for maximum overlap

Tags: python, algorithm, overlap

Let's say I have this set of strings:

```
strings = {'qqq', 'eqq', 'qqw', 'www', 'qww', 'wwe', 'eee', 'eeq', 'wee', 'qwe'}
```

How do I write an algorithm that arranges the strings such that they overlap maximally? I already know that one way of arranging them is as follows:

```
qww
 www
  wwe
   wee
    eee
     eeq
      eqq
       qqq
        qqw
         qwe
```

However, I found the above result with a brute-force solution. Is there a cleverer way of doing this?

Comment: This looks like something from Rosalind.info.

Comment: just thinking off the top of my head: Graph with strings as vertices, and edges as amount of overlap. do graph traversal to find shortest path including all vertices with maximum cost?

Comment: @Bill I've never heard of that before, but I did realize as I was working on this that it's kind of similar to matching DNA sequences. To anyone who really wants to know, it's related to a hero called Invoker in the game Dota 2. He can have 3 orbs (q, w or e) active at the same time, and he can use his active orbs to invoke a spell based on the combination of his orbs. This was to figure out the minimum number of keystrokes required to invoke all 10 of his spells.

Comment: @Lanaru: As Peter de Rivaz's answer implies, the problem is NP-complete, so your brute force algorithm is already optimal if you need a perfect answer. But since your problem space is tiny (2^N=1024), who cares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the shortest superstring problem and is NP complete.

You might be interested in the approaches in the paper [Approximation Algorithms for the Shortest Common Superstring Problem by Jonathan Turner](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0890540189900448).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's always fun discovering that problems you stumble upon in your own time have already been analyzed and researched. I'm currently pursuing a bachelor in Software Engineering so I thought I could apply my knowledge to come up with a clever solution (optimization problem solving, or dynamic programming or something). I then gave up and went for a brute force method. Good to see that the problem isn't that easy!

Comment: If you want a fun challenge, then try thinking about an algorithm to see if it is possible to join all your strings together so that each pair overlaps by a single character.  There is a very nice efficient solution to this modified problem :)

Comment: That link to the 20-page article in "Information and Computation" ([DOI 10.1016/0890-5401(89)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0890-5401(89)90044-8)) looks stale.

Comment: There is also this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem) with the NP-complete definition